# Necessary and Sufficient Property Restrictions in OWL

Tags: logic, owl, ontology

So I was reading [this](http://www.cs.vu.nl//~guus/public/owl-restrictions/) and it says:

> As an example of a necessary and sufficient condition, take a look at
>   the following definition:
>
> `:RedThing   a owl:Class ;   owl:equivalentClass
>        [ a owl:Restriction ;
>          owl:onProperty :color ;
>          owl:hasValue red^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string>
>        ]`

What I interpret this to mean is that if something is red, then that thing must be a `RedThing`.Also, if something is a `RedThing`, then it must be the color red.

When I added this code snippet to Protege, and I write:

`:test_subject :color red^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string>`

Then the following is inferred by the reasoner:

`:test_subject rdf:type :RedThing`

What this covers is the necessary part of the restriction definition, i.e. if something is red, then that thing must be a `RedThing`.

When I add the following to an ontology (again using Protege):

`test_subject_2 rdf:type :RedThing`

Then the following SHOULD be inferred by the reasoner:

`:test_subject_2 :color red^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string>`

Because this is the sufficient part of the condition. i.e  if something is a `RedThing`, then it must be the color red.

BUT it is NOT inferred. What am I missing here?

Comment: Which reasoner are you using?

Comment: I tried faCT++ and Hermit 1.3.8 - same results

Comment: Data type property inferences aren't shown by default.  You may need to check the setting to display them.   See the next to last image in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21499584/1281433).

Comment: Okay I did that, restarted the reasoner, and I get the same results. BUT I just realized now that when I do a DL query, it says the test_subject_2 instance color is "red". So I think I'm all good and there must be some other reason why the data type inference isn't showing up